# Docker swarm mode: discover local service

Tags: docker, protocol-buffers, service-discovery

In my docker swarm cluster I have a *lease* service. It is deployed on each swarm node in a container as a docker service (via the `--mode=global` switch) and exposes its service via a TCP/IP port. All other containers have to get a lease from their **node-local** *lease* service before they are allowed to run.

**How can a container resolve the IP address of the node-local container running the *lease* service?**

Some notes:

- I know swarm comes with DNS service discovery. AFAIK this might return the address of a remote container which would break my system.
- Since every container has to contact the *lease* service on startup latency is an issue. So, probing all IPs on the docker internal network is not an option.

Comment: that was an old bug in docker swarm, when you connect to remote container, the connection goes in timeout, now in the new version, that problem is solved

Comment: You mean in older Docker versions I might have ended up on a remote node, but in recent ones, I'm guaranteed to always end up at the node-local service? Is there any documentation comment, github issue, etc for this?

Comment: @fzgregor probably this comes too late but, have you tried using the network in host mode for the lease service, then your other containers should be able to use the host network to get the lease and the overlay network afterwards